# higlight whole word if first 3 chars are valid

Tags: php

I got some function (part of):

```
foreach ($keyword as $key) {                                                                                                            
    $keyword = substr($key, 0, 3);                                                                                                      
    $para = preg_replace("/\b([a-z]*${keyword}[a-z]*)\b/i","<span style='color:#20a8d8'>$1</span>",$para);
}
```

and now I can highlight results of my foreach loop, of course only first 3 chars, how can i highlight whole word where 3 first chars are valid ?

I tried also:

```
foreach ($paras as $para) {
    $keyword = explode(" ", $keyword);

    foreach ($keyword as $key) {
        $keywordcheck = substr($key, 0, 3);
        $paracheck = preg_replace("/\b([a-z]*${keywordcheck}[a-z]*)\b/i","<span style='color:#20a8d8'>$1</span>",$para);
        if (isset($paracheck)) {
            $para = preg_replace("/\b([a-z]*${keyword}[a-z]*)\b/i","<span style='color:#20a8d8'>$1</span>",$para);
        }
    }
}
```

new code:

```
foreach ($paras as $para) {                 
    $keyword = explode(" ", $keyword);

    foreach ($keyword as $key) {
        $key = substr($key, 0, 3);
        $para = preg_replace("/\b({$key}[a-z]*)\b/i","<span style='color:#20a8d8'>$1</span>", $para);
    }   

    echo '<tr><td style="width:15%"></td>';                 
    echo '<td>';
    echo 'META TITLE: '.$para.'';
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: What is "valid"?

Comment: sorry..... "fit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$para = "Microsoft is company placed in USA";
$keyword = ['com'];

foreach ($keyword as $key) {
    $kw = substr($key, 0, 3);
    $para = preg_replace("/\b({$kw}[-a-z]*)\b/i","<span style='color:#20a8d8'>$1</span>", $para);
}

echo $para;
```

http://ideone.com/rGb5q8

Comment: works, but i need to grap only one word in whole string, this hilights me a all from left to right, left ist start where fit kw

Comment: Could you show an example text and what should be highlighted there?

Comment: Example test: Microsoft is company placed in USA
$keyword = 'com';

Highlighted: company

Comment: The pattern above does it with your example. But If you need only 1 match then add limit 1 to preg_replace (the fourth parameter).

Comment: ok but, now highlite only every second result of params my code is updated

Comment: ok ok, it works, problem was that expload was in forach loop, so job done, thx ! cool solution

Comment: one question more, what if in this text is more than 2 or 3 fit key ?
ok just remove limit in preg_replace, got it! THX

Comment: The example above will find all of them. If you want to highlight only first one then you should add limit as the fourth parameter in preg_replace()

Comment: As you pointed out a "problem" with my answer. There is a problem with yours too. `$para = "Microsoft is world-wide company placed in USA";
$keyword = ['wor'];` https://3v4l.org/JtRvo we can nitpick errors on each others answers all day. But I think OP should decide the "rules" of the sentences and how/what to highlight.

Comment: It will also fail all caps words or mix of upper/lower case.

Comment: @Andreas I have updated the pattern. Now it includes "-". There is no fail with upper/lower https://3v4l.org/lkgZN

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the string and use Substr to check the first three of each word in a foreach.
I use str_replace to replace the word with the word enclosed in the span tag.

```
    $str = "a life with fitness is boring but it may fit some people. Apples new iFit is not highlighted";

$arr = explode(" ", $str);

Foreach($arr as &$word){
    If(Substr($word,0,3) == "peo"){
       // If word has a . Or any other special character after the word handle it.
       If(ctype_alpha(Substr($word,-1))){
           $word = str_replace($word, "<span style='color:#20a8d8'>".$word."</span>", $word);
       }Else{
           $char = substr($word,-1); //if it has a dot this "saves" it
            // Here I remove the dot, and insert it last (after span)
           $word = str_replace($word, "<span style='color:#20a8d8'>".substr($word,0,-1)."</span>", $word) . $char;
       }
    }
}

Echo implode(" ", $arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/WkK5j

In my opinion there is no reason to use regex since it's not really a pattern. It's only the first three characters.

Edited to make sure it does not highlight the `.` in people.

Comment: If the first 3 chars will be "peo" then you will get "people." (with dot at the end). Also you add an additional foreach because there is an array of keywords.

Comment: ok but how to replace "fit" with what ? wich variable ?

if(substr($word,0,3) = ?? {...

Comment: @Talgat what array of keywords? See comment above where I ask what is valid.

Comment: @Commander yes. That is correct. You could also use a $search = "fit"; and `if(substr($word,0,3) == $search)`

Comment: @Andreas I meant this array `$keyword = explode(" ", $keyword);`

Comment: @Talgat that was added after I posted my answer. Or while I posted. The initial question was one word "fit". Or actually, initially there was only "valid" three characters.

Comment: @Andreas I don't blame you. Don't worry at all. The main notice was that str_replace returns wrong result when dot or other special chars at the end of the word.

Comment: @Andreas I see you have updated. But what about "people!!" or "people:-)"? Do you still think str_replace is better than regex in this case?

Comment: @Talgat yes I do find str_replace better for most situations. And the reason is that regex has a massive overhead which normal string operations does not. If the question was with !!! Or Smiley's and such then yes there may be a benefit of regex. But it's **all** about what you are trying to do. If the text you are scanning is machine written it's highly unlikely that there is two or three !. But if it's a blog about a 13 year old girls horse I wouldn't dare use any functions at all. There is no right and wrong for a generic question, if the question was specific "13 year old girls blogg"....

Comment: @Andreas I don't argue with what's faster and lightweight. I said only about this case. We don't know exactly what will be in the input string. So I suppose that there may be anything (even tags like </div>).